# Keep getting the 404 Not Found error on Postman when using the Reddit API what seems to me a perfectly legit request

Tags: postman, reddit

I am trying to simply return an username i specify in the request to test if an user exists.

To replicate the issue:

URL:
https://oauth.reddit.com/api/v1/user/*usernamehere*/about

Type of request: POST

Headers:
User-Agent: My app
Authorization: Bearer *MyTokenHere*
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I am 100% positive the token I am using is valid.

If I change the request to GET I get the Bad Request error.

Anyone can help?

I was expecting some successful payload about an user and not an error